# The results of same query are different when other clients execute the query to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I post this article because I experienced an issue that I cannot understand.

The problem is that the results of the same query are different when each other clients execute the query to mongodb.

I don't have confidence to explain shortly... To be specific, our web service has been working with mongodb shard cluster(4 primary, 4 secondary nodes) for about 1 year, and we consist of a variety of back-end services for statistics. There are some clients such as mongodb java driver and python driver for each service.

One day, we realized that the results of a query for aggregation are wrong because our planning team pointed out that the count in real web service and aggregation is different. Firstly, we doubted that the aggregation service developed by python is wrong since we hadn't experienced it for running web service. So, we passed it because we thought that it was REALLY impossible.

After 15 days, however, we met with this issue again. The query was simple, but the results by python driver and by java driver for web services are different. For example, the count of rows in web service used mongo java driver 3.6.3 is 90, but the count of rows in stats service by python is 15. In addition, it was 15 when we checked by robo mongo. The strange thing was that it was correct when I executed exactly the same query by connecting mongos shell directly. More strange thing is that the query by python and robo mongo became correctly after executing the same query in the shell.
Next, we guessed that the issue occurred because of the client. So, we tracked the versions of clients we used. the versions are as below.

```
mongodb java driver for web service : 3.6.3
mongodb java driver for presto : 3.6.0
pymongo for stats service : 3.7.2
Robo 3T 1.2.1
```

However, we realized that Robo 3T embeds real mongodb shell. Our supposition was incorrect. Finally, I'm writing thie article.. ;(

I think that it is very difficult to find the cause of this issue, but I expect that some nice mongodb user gives small advice for analyzing this cause.

Thank you.